# pgfplots: Two half-planes (Gödel logic graph)

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to plot the function 
 `(x <= y) * (1) + (x > y) * (y)` 
which should give two triangle-styled areas.

**(1)** With the first try

```
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1, domain y=0:1
]{   (x <= y) * (1) + (x > y) * (y)   };
```

I get a bad result, because the areas are connected.

**(2)** So I split into two functions and use `restrict z to domain=<..>`.

But now I get zigzag at the margins and gaps to the origin of the second area.

Which settings should use?

**Hint**: *It is clear how to use straight lines and fill between here I would like to figure out how to use the shown functions here with pgfplots.*

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=7cm,
colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white); color(1cm) = (black)},
every axis plot post/.append style={cyan},
%fill=cyan,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={Bad - areas connected}, xtick={0,0.5,1}, ytick={0,0.5,1}, ztick={0,0.5,1},
xlabel=$p$, ylabel=$q$, zmin=0, zmax=1, small]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1, domain y=0:1
]{   (x <= y) * (1) + (x > y) * (y)   };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={Better but not perfect: gaps and zigzags}, xtick={0,0.5,1}, ytick={0,0.5,1}, ztick={0,0.5,1},
xlabel=$p$, ylabel=$q$, zmin=0, zmax=1, small]
\addplot3[surf, cyan, 
domain=0:1, domain y=0:1,
restrict z to domain=1:1, 
]{    (x <= y ) * (1)     };

\addplot3[surf,
domain=0:1, domain y=0:1,
restrict z to domain=0.000001:1,% not good
]{   (x > y) * (y)     };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of plotting a function, you could just use the corner coordinates for the desired plane. -or look into the `patch type`. Here are examples: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: Yes, thats clear. For reasons of elegance I would like to figure out how to use the shown functions here with pgfplots.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly, what OP is looking for, but for reasons of elegance, I show the patch plot:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5 cm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[patch, patch refines=8, cyan] coordinates {(0,0,1) (1,1,1) (0,1,1) };
\addplot3[patch, patch refines=8, cyan] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,1,1) (1,0,0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Patch plot of the two surfaces]